# Expectation value of the coherent term

Tags: quantum-state, measurement

I am trying to and understand a statement of a paper I am reading [URL](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.140504). Figure 3c shows the circuit.
$\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle #1\rvert}\newcommand{\braket}[2]{\langle #1\rvert #2\rangle}\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert #1\rangle}\newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}\newcommand{\ketbra}[2]{\lvert #1\rangle\!\langle #2\rvert}$

There is mentioned that the result of an quantum circuit can be read out by measure the expectation value of the coherent term of the ancillary qubit $\ket{000}\bra{000} \otimes \ket{1}_A \bra{0}_A$.

What is the coherent term?
Is'n the solution of this equation a matrix? How does a matrix have an expectation value that can be read out of a measurement of a quantum circuit?